# Gulpで複数入力・出力パスを指定する方法（例としてgulp-sass）

Tags: gulp, sass

プロジェクトフォルダ構造：

development
　 public
　　 1sass
　　 2css
　 admin
　　 3sass
　　 4css

どちらのソースフォルダーが、どちらの出力フォルダに相当しているか、`gulp`は何れかの方法で簡単に判断できないように、私はフォルダに数字を付けた結果、名前が同じのフォルダが無くなりました。

さて、`gulp-sass`を使って、**/public**フォルダの中にも、**/admin**フォルダの中にも、**/sass**にあるファイルを`.css`にコンパイルし、それぞれ**public/2css**、**admin/4css**に置きたいと思います：

public/1sass →  public/2css
 admin/3sass →  admin/4css

適切な`gulpfile`タスク設定の例をなかなか見つけないんですが・・・

`gulp.src()`に、一つのパスの代わりにパスの配列を伝えても、どうやって`gulp`は入力・出力パスの相当性を判断するでしょうか。

もしかして、二つの`sass`タスクを定義し、gulp v.4.x に出来た`gulp.parallell()`を使うしかないでしょうか？

Comment: 英語版マルチポスト: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46998328/4698341

Comment: @hinaloそれも私の質問でした　笑

Comment: 他の質問でもロシア語版、英語版、日本語版においてマルチポスト(クロスポスト)されているようですが、できるだけそのことは質問にリンク付きで明記するようにしてください。（できれば避けるべきですが） https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1770/2376 もご確認を。